# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) [list]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contain 4 columns:
`"Date"`, `"Num_week"`, `"Calendar"`

`df.head()` looks like:

```
    Date    Num_week    Calendar
412 2012-01-01  1      (2012, 1)
413 2012-01-02  2      (2012, 1)
414 2012-01-03  2      (2012, 1)
415 2012-01-04  2      (2012, 1)
416 2012-01-05  2      (2012, 1)
```

I sord values in column:  `sorted(list(set(date_week['calendar'])))`

*result*:

```
['(2012, 1)',
 '(2012, 10)',
 '(2012, 11)',
 '(2012, 12)',
 '(2012, 2)',
 '(2012, 3)', etc.
```

And I try to get year and month separeted in loop.

```
for year, month in list(set(date_week['calendar'])):
    print(year, month)
```

But get ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-cf01e0d2888e> in <module>()
----> 1 for year, month in list(set(date_week['calendar'])):
      2     print(year, month)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I've already tried use `.items()` and get wrong result.

Could you help me to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there are no tuples, but string repr of tuples, so need converting first:

```
import ast
date_week['Calendar'] = date_week['Calendar'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

So possible use your solution or alternative:

```
for year, month in date_week['Calendar'].unique():
    print(year, month)
    2012 1
```

EDIT: Alternative solution with [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and converting to tuples:

```
date_week['Calendar'] = date_week['Calendar'].str.findall('\d+').apply(tuple)
print (date_week)
           Date  Num_week   Calendar
412  2012-01-01         1  (2012, 1)
413  2012-01-02         2  (2012, 1)
414  2012-01-03         2  (2012, 1)
415  2012-01-04         2  (2012, 1)
416  2012-01-05         2  (2012, 1)
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggest and get another error `ValueError: malformed node or string: (2012, 1)`

Comment: @D.Mae - Added new solution.

Comment: Thank you! But i get another error `'float' object is not iterable` with new solution.

Comment: @D.Mae - I think possible missing values, so need change `date_week['Calendar'].unique()` to `date_week['Calendar'].dropna().unique()`

Comment: `Int64Index: 2672 entries, 412 to 3083
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Date                   2672 non-null object
Num_week               2672 non-null int64
calendar    2672 non-null object`
There is not any missing val

Answer (score 1):

```
date_week

           Date  Num_week   Calender
412  2012-01-01         1  (2012, 1)
413  2012-01-02         2  (2012, 1)
414  2012-01-03         2  (2012, 1)
415  2012-01-04         2  (2012, 1)
416  2012-01-05         2  (2012, 1)
```

**Solution 1:** Get output in list

```
l = list(zip(*df['Calender']))
[(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

OR

```
y,m = list(zip(*df['Calender']))
year = list(y)
month = list(m)
```

Output:

```
print(year)
[2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012]

print(month)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Solution 2:**
You can create separate dataframe columns

```
ym = pd.DataFrame(df['Calender'].values.tolist(), columns=['year','month'], index=date_week.index)
ym

     year  month
412  2012      1
413  2012      1
414  2012      1
415  2012      1
416  2012      1
```

and merge with existing dataframe

```
date_week_new = pd.concat([df, ym],axis=1)
date_week_new 

           Date  Num_week   Calender  year  month
412  2012-01-01         1  (2012, 1)  2012      1
413  2012-01-02         2  (2012, 1)  2012      1
414  2012-01-03         2  (2012, 1)  2012      1
415  2012-01-04         2  (2012, 1)  2012      1
416  2012-01-05         2  (2012, 1)  2012      1
```